# Redimensionamento responsivo de células <th> <td>

Tags: html, css

Como ajustar o tamanho de células de modo que fiquem responsivas?

```
<body>

    <div class="corpo">
        <main class="tabela">
            <table>
                <tr>

                    <th class="t">SEGUNDA</th>
                    <th class="t">TERÇA</th>
                    <th class="t">QUARTA</th>
                    <th class="t">QUINTA</th>
                    <th class="t">SEXTA</th>
                    <th class="t">SABADO</th>
                    <th class="t">DOMINGO</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>a</td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

Com ***px*** acabam excedendo o limite da ***div***,
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 e ***%*** termina que uma (sempre a primeira) acaba sempre maior que as demais.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<style>
    .corpo {
        width: 90%;
        background-color: #60606048;
        margin: auto;

    }

    tr{
        border: 1px solid #606060;
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 10%;

    }
    .t{
        background-color: aquamarine;
        width: 15%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro que você está usando um valor inválido na cor `background-color: #60606048;`.

Segundo é que a a sua tabela é responsiva, mas numa determinada largura onde o texto dentro das `th` ficam maiores que a largura da coluna e o texto não irá "quebrar".

Para resolver isso, user a propriedade `word-break: break-all;`, assim o texto irá "quebrar" para baixo quando a largura da coluna for menor que a largura do texto:

```css
.corpo {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;

}

tr{
  border: 1px solid #606060;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.t{
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="corpo">
  <main class="tabela">
      <table>
          <tr>

              <th class="t">SEGUNDA</th>
              <th class="t">TERÇA</th>
              <th class="t">QUARTA</th>
              <th class="t">QUINTA</th>
              <th class="t">SEXTA</th>
              <th class="t">SABADO</th>
              <th class="t">DOMINGO</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>a</td>

          </tr>
      </table>
  </main>
</div>
```